# Puppet and managing .k5login with parameters and arrays

Tags: puppet

So I have Foreman set up, and would like to pass in a parameter that is basically a way to easily specify users and groups that can log in as that user. My idea is currently to have the parameter take this sort of input:

user1;group1,group2,group3.user2;group1,groupn.user3;group1

Normally (in other languages), I'd make a 2 dimensional array and then loop through it. This isn't really something that can be done in Puppet though.

I've written a custom function to expand out the group members, and then pass that into the k5login type. My next thought is to create a defined type for that. I'm just not sure if I can pass in 2 values... And am I re-inventing the wheel, or am I doing something sort of stupid here?

Comment: Is there a reason you would not use data structured as hashes and arrays? Such as `{ user1 => [ group1, ... ], user2 => ... }`

Comment: I'm not sure if I can pass a hash / array as a parameter from The Foreman?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the "flatten" function from puppet-stdlib.

```
This function flattens any deeply nested arrays and returns a single flat array
as a result.

*Examples:*

    flatten(['a', ['b', ['c']]])

Would return: ['a','b','c']
```

https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib

We use it to do something like this:

```
$flattened = join(unique(sort(flatten([$host_array1,$host_array2,$host_array3]))), ',' )
```